# How to pass id to the bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am using bootstrap modal to display member's information. Each member has the button to open the modal. I have this button in loop:

```
@foreach($members as $member)
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View Details</button>
@endforeach
```

This modal content:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Member Detail Information</h4>
             </div>

             <div class="modal-body">
                  {{$member->name}}
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
   </div>
```

But everytime I get the last member's information. This is obvious but i want to pass the `$member->ID` from the button and dispaly their respective details in the modal. How Can I acheive this?

Comment: You're getting confused between client side and server side. When your `foreach` loop finishes, the `$member` variable contains the last member data. It sounds like you want to either AJAX in the member data when a modal is opened, or use some JavaScript to populate it. Are you using any front-end JavaScript frameworks? VueJS, ReactJS, AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data` attribute to pass some data into Bootstrap modal.

Buttons in the loop

```
@foreach()

     <a data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$member->name}}" href="#UserDialog" class="user_dialog">Details</a>

@endforeach
```

Bootstrap model

```
<div class="modal hide" id="UserDialog">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>some content</p>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And little JavaScript

```
$(document).on("click", ".user_dialog", function () {
     var UserName = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #user_name").val( UserName );
});
```

That's it

Little demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/6247/